# Autocomplete braces within braces in Geany?

Tags: autocomplete, curly-braces, geany

I am programming in Java, and whenever I type a `{` within a class Geany doesn't autocomplete for me since it assumes the ending brace to the brace I just typed is the ending brace for the class. Is there any way to disable this so that no matter what when I type a `{`, it will autocomplete to `{}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can improve and configure behaviour of closing braces by using and configuring [autoclose-plugin](http://plugins.geany.org/autoclose.html). Having this activated I getting the wished behaviour.